# Why does git push move files from folder?

Tags: github, git-push

`git push` moves all files from local to remote leaving behind an empty folder.

I pushed files from my local to remote but realized my files in the local folder from which I pushed are no longer available in the local folder. Why does it do that?

Comment: As far as I know, `git push` should not do that.  You must have run some other command that moved/deleted/renamed the files.